# How to programmatically register customer if email_id not exist

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

I have created a custom page in magento, from this I want to send coupon code to customer `which are new and already registered` both. For this I have created a custom form with all information I needed, on submit form I am calling a ajax and my custom module handle this request.

But How to identify there that it is new customer and How to create a new customer account in controller action?

Comment: Pls check my answer it will helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try something like below:**

```
$customer_email = 'test@gmail.com';  // email adress that will pass by the questionaire 
    $customer_fname = 'test_firstname';      // we can set a tempory firstname here 
    $customer_lname = 'test_lastname';       // we can set a tempory lastname here 
    $passwordLength = 10;                    // the lenght of autogenerated password

    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
    $customer->loadByEmail($customer_email);
    /*
    * Check if the email exist on the system.
    * If YES,  it will not create a user account. 
    */

    if(!$customer->getId()) {
        $customer->setEmail($customer_email);
        $customer->setFirstname($customer_fname);
        $customer->setLastname($customer_lname);
        $customer->setPassword($customer->generatePassword($passwordLength));
    }
    try {
        $customer->save();
        $customer->setConfirmation(null);
        $customer->save();

        // Send welcome email
        $storeId = $customer->getSendemailStoreId();
        $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('registered', '', $storeId);
        //Make a "login" of new customer
        //Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId());

    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
       echo 'error';
    }
```

Comment: Implementing your code, will let you know if it is working.

Comment: It is working, but not getting welcome email on new customer register.

Comment: And also when customer checked newsletter checkbox, how it will be saved and send newsletter email to customer?

Comment: use : $customer->setIsSubscribed(true);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47118/discussion-between-nikunj-vadariya-and-vinaya-maheshwari).

Answer (score 0):

use this code for check Customer Exist

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->loadByEmail($customer_email);

if($customer->getId())
{
  "Customer Exist";
}
```

add add this this code
https://www.onlinecode.org/customer-rgistration-programmatically-magento/